# i need help and advice about django admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I'm new with python and Django. I know a lot about the Codeigniter framework and there if you want to create a project like an eCommerce you must create an admin panel with template and function for the backend. 
when I was creating backend I was adding functions for the admin panel where all functions were for adding some informations in the database.
so when I start with Django I saw that there was an integrated admin panel which can be modified but I have a question can I create app for Django which will be admin panel of my project and can I deactivate or delete integrated admin panel or can I add some functions and redesign integrated one

Comment: First URL on google... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can "deactivate" the admin site. The easiest way would be to just remove the admin site url from your `urls.py` file. E.g (for my stock database) remove this line:

```
path('stock/admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can "deactivate" the admin site. The easiest way would be to just remove the admin site URL from your `urls.py` file.

E.g (for my stock database) remove this line:

```
path('stock/admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

Comment: yes thanks but there was question not about deactivation.. please read and if you can answer